# Netbeans debugger doesn't run to break point or offer options (step into, over etc)

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

In Netbeans debugger, when I put a break point on the first few lines of code it works fine. However, anything below the "try" the application hangs, the highlight does not turn green and the options to step into, etc, are grayed out. (also the Boolean 'BigList' IS true, so that's not the issue).

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //process declines  
    setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
    JFrame f;
    f = new JFrame("Frame");
    final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(f, true); // modal
       
    dialog.setUndecorated(true);
    JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar();
    bar.setIndeterminate(true);
    bar.setStringPainted(true);
    bar.setString("Please wait");
    dialog.setLocation(100, 100);
    dialog.add(bar);
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
        
    
    try {
        String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1:3306/common";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "pass";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = null;
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, password);
        if (bigList) {
```

Comment: Could the program be waiting for you to interact with a dialog box or other component? Try minimizing the NetBeans window to check.

Comment: I experienced in the past that NetBeans was not "accepting" breakpoints and the deletion of the cache was the only solution. Btw.: the name for the Driver class you use is since 5 years deprecated (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html) and `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` should be used instead.